# How to calculate board feet for project I'm working on

Tags: wood, wood-selection, measurement

The whole board feet deal is a little confusing to me. If I have a 2" x 2" x 36" board, how many board feet does that add up to? Is it 1 board foot? Trying to figure out how much to order for a butcher block countertop I'm working on.

Answer (score 2):

A board foot is a measure of volume, answering the question "how much wood?". It equates to 144 cubic inches; a board 12" x 12" x 1" thick is one board foot.

So you can calculate the volume in cubic inches and divide by 144:

```
2 x 2 x 36 = 144 = 1 board foot
```

To calculate this in their head, folks might figure the equivalent board feet of a 12-inch length of the board and then multiply by the length, for example with a 2 x 10 that's 8 feet long:

```
2 x 10 = 20; 20/12 = 5/3 board foot per foot
5/3 x 8 feet = 40/3 = 13-1/3 board feet
```